# aspx gridview Enabled button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Here is my asp code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPresmetka" runat="server" BackColor="White"
        BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
         PageSize="15">
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
             <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
             <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Прикачи Документи"><ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Прикачи" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                  </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Провери"><ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="lnkProveri" runat="server" Text="Прикачи" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return Proveri(this)" BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Enabled="False" />
                  </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
            var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;

            var id = row.cells[2].innerHTML;

            var url = "google.aspx?id=" + id + "&amp;status=00";
            popitup(url);

            return false;
        }
```

How can I make the second button " ID="lnkProveri" " enable=true with JavaScript when (after) I click the first button  " ID="lnkSelect" "

PS. the project is with VB.Net and compailer is IE=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to be aware HTML code rendered

```
<td>
  <input type="submit" name="grdPresmetka$ctl12$lnkSelect" value="Прикачи" onclick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" id="grdPresmetka_lnkSelect_10" style="color:#CCCCFF;background-color:#003399;font-weight:bold;">
</td><td>
 <input type="submit" name="grdPresmetka$ctl12$lnkProveri" value="Прикачи" id="grdPresmetka_lnkProveri_10" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" style="color:#CCCCFF;background-color:#003399;font-weight:bold;">
</td>
```

We need to refer from one buttons to the other. One possibility is to use the fact that the buttons are in the same table row and find a button in the next cell (with jquery).

```
$(lnk).closest("td").next().find('input').prop("disabled", false);
```

Another possibility is to use how ids are costructed `grdPresmetka_lnkSelect_*` and `grdPresmetka_lnkProveri_*`. 
When we take the assumption that button id does not contain underscore the following code is a solution

```
var items = lnk.id.split("_")             
items[items.length - 2] = "lnkProveri"
var elem = document.getElementById(items.join("_"));
elem.disabled = false;
```

Be aware that both code fragments are supposed to be added to the beginning of the function `GetSelectedRow`